# Comprobar tipo objeto Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy haciendo un desarrollo con angular + typescript.

Tengo un Componente al que le pueden llegar 3 tipos de listas.

¿Es posible saber el tipo de objeto que estoy recibiendo en el componente?

El porque de este uso es porque he creado un componente "Tabla", que lo utilizo para mostrar todas las tablas que tengo en la web y puede ser de esos 3 tipos

Clase Panel, de esta clase bindeo el content hacia el componente "Tabla"

```
import { Bike } from './bike.class';
import { Club } from './club.class';
import { Shoe } from './shoe.class';

export class Panel {
    disabled: boolean = false;
    name: string = '';
    content: (Club | Shoe | Bike)[];

    constructor(
        disabled: boolean,
        name: string,
        content: (Club | Shoe | Bike)[]
    ) {
        this.disabled = disabled;
        this.name = name;
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

El componente "Tabla" que es donde quiero identificar el tipo de objeto que le estoy pasando para pintar unas columnas u otras en el grid

```
import { Component, Input, Type } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseComponent } from '../../base/base.component';
import { Bike } from '../../../core/models/bike.class';
import { Club } from '../../../core/models/club.class';
import { Shoe } from 'src/app/core/models/shoe.class';

@Component({
    selector: 'ui-table',
    templateUrl: './table.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./table.component.scss'],
})
export class TableComponent extends BaseComponent {
    @Input() items: (Club | Shoe | Bike)[] = [];
    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

El objetivo sería saber que tipo recibe el ítems

Comment: Mira este ejemplo que te dejo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-eo7jpw?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.ts

Comment: Puede que tu problema venga de que no estas creando una clase como tal, si no un objeto.

Comment: Pues tenéis toda la razón, son objetos. Es posible el hacer esto mismo que comento, pero para saber el tipo de objeto que compone la lista?

Comment: Comprobar tipos en Typescript puede ser algo complejo, sobre todo si los elementos que deseamos comprobar no han sido definidos correctamente, por ejemplo, esto: `items: Collection[] = []` podrías convertirlo a: `items: Bike[] | Club[] | Shoe[] = [];` Por otro lado, debes verificar que cada elemento de la lista sea del tipo que esperas. En principio tienes 4 tipos: Club, Bike, Shoe y Collection. Toma en cuenta que todo elemento de tipo Bike, Club o Shoe también es de tipo Collection.

Comment: Además, al momento de iniciar el componente, si la lista está vacía, ¿cómo pretendes saber el tipo de elemento que tendrá la misma? No me queda claro lo que pretendes comprobar realmente. El hecho de definir un tipo para una lista vacía sólo te ayudará al momento de añadir elementos a la misma durante la codificación, ya que Typescript te advertirá que no puede añadir un elemento con tipo diferente del esperado. Pero en tiempo de ejecución las cosas cambian.

Comment: Edito la pregunta inicial y te meto algo de código que he ido trabajando durante la tarde

Comment: @Diego Si estos datos los recibes en un servicio, estas creando un objeto y ese objeto debe ser pasado a una clase con `new TuClase(tuObjeto)`. La alternativa que yo prefiero, es poner una propiedad string que diga el tipo de datos `_tipo_de_dato="Bike"`. En lo personal, deje de usar clases y empecé a usar interfaces para evitar algunos problemas como este.

Comment: Diego y @Legna los invito al [chat], para discutir un poco este asunto, antes de darte una respuesta, ya que no suelo utilizar Angular tanto como me gustaría y tengo algunos conceptos un poco oxidados.

Comment: para distinguir objetos por sus propiedades  interface Club {
socio:number
}
interface Zapato{
  numero:number,
  marca:string

}
interface Bicicleta{
  precio:number
}
let items:(Club | Zapato | Bicicleta)[] = [];
let belgrano:Club[]=[{socio:124}];
let otro:Zapato[]=[{marca:'tres',numero:42}];

const tg = (x: any): x is Club => x.socio;
console.log(tg(belgrano[0]));
console.log(tg(otro[0]));//undefine

Comment: tambien con function determina(x: Club | Zapato | Bicicleta): x is Club {
  if((x as Club).socio){
  
    return true
  }
  return false
}
console.log('determina',determina(belgrano[0]));//true
console.log('determina',determina(otro[0]));//false

Answer (score 0):

En el caso de clases

```js
class Employee {
  constructor(
    public identifier: string
  ) {}
  getIdentifier() {
    return this.identifier;
  }

  isSameEmployeeAs(employee: Employee) {
    return this.identifier === employee.identifier;
  }
}


class Warehouse {
  constructor(
     public identifier: string,public size:string
  ) {}
}
const Joaquin=new Employee('jefe');
const Alameda=new Warehouse('Grande','1000 metros cuadrados');
const empleados:Employee[]=[Joaquin];
const depositos:Warehouse[]=[Alameda];
let items: (Employee| Warehouse)[] = [Joaquin];
console.log(items[0]instanceof Warehouse);//false
console.log('typeof items[0] ',typeof items[0].identifier);
console.log(items[0] instanceof Employee);//true
 console.log('Warehouse.prototype.constructor.name',Warehouse.prototype.constructor.name);
console.log('Employee.prototype.constructor.name',Employee.prototype.constructor.name);

console.log( 'Joaquin.constructor.name',Joaquin.constructor.name);
console.log('Alameda.constructor.name', Alameda.constructor.name);
```

> Podemos distinguir a los objetos por sus propiedades

```js
  
interface Club {
socio:number
}
interface Zapato{
  numero:number,
  marca:string

}
interface Bicicleta{
  precio:number
}
let items:(Club | Zapato | Bicicleta)[] = [];
let belgrano:Club[]=[{socio:124}];
let otro:Zapato[]=[{marca:'tres',numero:42}];
  
const tg = (x: any): x is Club => x.socio;
console.log(tg(belgrano[0]));//124
console.log(tg(otro[0]));//undefine

function determina(x: Club | Zapato | Bicicleta): x is Club {
  if((x as Club).socio){
  
    return true
  }
  return false
}
console.log('determina',determina(belgrano[0]));//true
console.log('determina',determina(otro[0]));//false
```

Con clase Base instanceof nos dira

```js
class Mascota {
  constructor(private name:string) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
const miMascota = new Mascota('Ancry');
class Pajaro extends Mascota {
  constructor(name:string, private color:string) {
    super(name);
    this.color = color;
  }
}
const miPajaro = new Pajaro('rex', 'red');
console.log('miPajaro instanceof Mascota',miPajaro instanceof Mascota);// true
```

En las clases si chequeamos de esta forma tener en cuenta las propiedades que distinguen a cada clase

```js
   const isEmployeeIdentifier=(check:any):check is Employee =>
(check as Employee).identifier !==undefined;
console.log('is Employee',isEmployeeIdentifier(Alameda));// true
```